# Replace a char inside a for-loop

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to apply `:search=replace`-syntax to `%%var` inside a for-loop in Batch?

I'm trying to replace all hyphens with colons inside the mac-addresses of a machine (and then use them). Unfortunately, my regular approach `set var=%var:-=:%` does not work inside a for loop.

```
    FOR /F "tokens=12 delims= " %%G IN ('ipconfig /all ^| find /I "Physical Address"') DO (
      SET var=%%G
      SET newmac=%var:-=:%
      wget https://api-server-uri/pxe/do-stuff?newmac=%newmac%
    )
```

The problem is that the value of `%var:-=:%` does not change along with `%%G` .

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) world.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks @Stephan !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephans comment:

```
    Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    FOR /F "tokens=12 delims= " %%G IN ('ipconfig /all ^| find /I "Physical Address"') DO (
      SET var=%%G
      wget https://api-server-uri/pxe/do-stuff?newmac=!var:-=:!
    )
```

Comment: if there is nothing else inside your `for` loop, you don't even need delayed expansion. Just `FOR /F "tokens=12 delims= " %%G IN ('ipconfig /all ^| find /I "Physical Address"') DO  SET var=%%G` and `wget https://api-server-uri/pxe/do-stuff?newmac=%var:-=:%`

Comment: @Stephan, you mean to put `wget` outside of the loop, right? obviously, this can only be done in case the loop iterates once only...

Comment: Try: `FOR /F "tokens=12-17 delims=- " %%G IN ('ipconfig /all ^| find /I "Physical Address"') DO wget https://api-server-uri/pxe/do-stuff?newmac=%%G:%%H:%%I:%%J:%%K:%%L`